# route submit button to custom path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to route a submit button to a specific path (page), but I believe my syntax is not accurate.

This is what I have now:

```
<%= submit_tag('Next (Step 2 of 3)'), customer_index_path %>
```

I am getting the error:

```
/Users/anmareewilliams/RailsApps/GroupOrderingCopy/app/views/products/index.html.erb:18: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
...bmit_tag('Next (Step 2 of 3)'), customer_index_path );@outpu...
...
```

I tried this as well:

```
<%= submit_tag'Next (Step 2 of 3)', customer_index_path %>
```

and got no errors in the text editor, but got a Rails error that said:

```
undefined method `stringify_keys' for "/customer/index":String
```

How can I accomplish routing my submit to a specific path?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't include `path` in [`submit_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-submit_tag).  You need to define the path in your `form`'s `action`.

```
<%= form_tag(customer_index_path) do %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Next (Step 2 of 3)' %> 
<% end %>
```

This should submit the form to `customer_index_path`.

**Update:**

To submit a `GET` request to `#customer_index_path`, you need to update the `form_tag` declaration as follows:

```
<%= form_tag(customer_index_path, method: :get) do %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Next (Step 2 of 3)' %> 
<% end %>
```

Comment: that makes a lot more sense, but now I am getting this error: No route matches [POST] "/customer/index"
 I have gotten this error before and understand it a bit. it is happening because the route is a get http verb and not a post. that being said I am not sure the proper way to fix that issue. I tried putting post "customer/index" in my routes but that doesn't seem right

Comment: @anmaree, correct you'll be getting the `No route matches [POST]...` because by default the form's method is `POST`.  If you need to use `GET` then you need to add `method: :get` to the `form_tag`.

Answer (score 2):

The path to your route must be contained within the argument list, so in the first iteration of your code, ensure that both arguments are contained within your parentheses:

```
<%= submit_tag('Next (Step 2 of 3)', options) %>
```

*Alternatively*, you can pass arguments to the function without parentheses. Make sure that there's a space between the `submit_tag` and the first argument:

```
<%= submit_tag 'Next (Step 2 of 3)', options %>
```

**UPDATE**:

Regarding the second argument you're passing to `submit_tag`, [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-submit_tag) say the following:

```
 submit_tag(value = "Save changes", options = {})
```

The following are valid options:

- :data - This option can be used to add custom data attributes.
- :disabled - If true, the user will not be able to use this input.
- Any other key creates standard HTML options for the tag.

Note that the path **is not** a valid value. Rather, the path should be passed as the argument to the opening `form_tag` helper.

*Also*, I'm assuming that – because you're not using a `form_for` – you don't have a resourceful route for this controller. Thus, you'll want to create a custom route for `customer_index_path`:

```
# config/routes.rb
get '/customers', to: 'customers#index', :as 'customers_index'
```

Comment: I am still getting the error: undefined method `stringify_keys' for "/customer/index":String

Comment: See my update. You can't pass a path as an argument to `submit_tag` – you should be passing the path to the opening `form_tag`. I've included a list of valid values for the second `options` argument in `submit_tag`.